# Reset default scope in relations, Yii 1.1

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii1.x

How can I reset default scope in relations?

**Query:**

```
$matches = MatchesStat::model()
->resetScope(true)
->with(array('best_player', 'bad_player'))
->findByAttributes(array(
            'match_id' => $this->id,
            'mode' => $this->mode
        ));
```

**Function relations():**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'best_player'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Players', '', 'on' => 't.best_pl = best_player.pl_id AND t.mode = best_player.mode', 'scopes' => array( 'resetScope' )),
        'bad_player'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Players', '', 'on' => 't.bad_pl = bad_player.pl_id AND t.mode = bad_player.mode', 'scopes' => array( 'resetScope' ))
    );
}
```

**Players, defaultScope:**

```
public function defaultScope()
    {
        return array(
            'condition' => $this->getTableAlias(false, false) . '.mode = "main"',
        );
    }
```

As you can see, I use 'scopes' => array( 'resetScope' ) in my relations. But:

[image]

Comment: try this query `MyModel::model()->resetScope()->findAll();`

Comment: I worote about the problem: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/3964